# style.display of undefined while the element is properly defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7qnz2e70/)

```
function toggleFoo() {
    var btn = $('button');

    btn.click(function () {
        var thisElem = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children');
        console.log(thisElem.length)
        thisElem.style.display = (thisElem.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleFoo();
});
```

Why am I getting `undefined` when trying to access `style.display` of the element that is defined properly and which `length` can be accessed?

Comment: just `thisElem.toggle()` instead of `thisElem.style.display = (thisElem.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';`

Comment: `thisElem` is a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), not a dom element reference so don't have `style` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thisElem` is a [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), not a [dom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) reference so it doesn't have `style` property.

If you just want to toggle the display of the element, then you can simply use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method from jQuery.

```js
function toggleFoo() {
  var btn = $('button');

  btn.click(function() {
    var thisElem = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children');
    console.log(thisElem.length)
    thisElem.toggle();
  });
};

$(document).ready(toggleFoo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <div class="children">
    <h2>foo</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to access the dom element, then you can say

```
var thisElem = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this for your output :

```
function toggleFoo() {
    var btn = $('button');

    btn.click(function () {
        var thisElem = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children');
        var display = (thisElem.css("display") == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
        thisElem.css("display",display);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleFoo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the dom to get the `style` property.

When you used `$(this).closest('.parent').find('.children');` the result is wrapped in a `jQuery` object. To get the dom element you add the key index of the element you are targetting. e.g. `[0]` in your case.

Hence:

`var thisElem = $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children')[0];`

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it only gets the first element of a possible set of elements.

Comment: It is an answer to the question. Not an answer to a general question. And in the question it is targeting the 1st element only.

Comment: The class name in OP's jQuery selector `.children` (plural!) already suggests a set of elements. So it **is** part of the question *implicitly*.

Comment: targeting `thisElem.style.display` is not for a set of elements.

Comment: True, this the part that had to be corrected for OP. What you did is correct the type of objects OP operates on whilst the need was to change the method retaining the object type.